# menu appearance

Tags: java, android, menu

I have a discrepancy in the menu appearance between two applications.

The first one is an "old" application I 'm extending to Android 15. For this, I have set the min SDK to 10 and the target SDK to 15.

The second one is a brand new one generated with the Eclipse's wizard. It's min SDK parameter is set to 8 and it's target SDK parameter to 15.

When I launch the second application, the menu looks like it should in an Android 4 environment : every menu item is in the overflow menu.

When I launch the first one, the menu looks the old way : 6 items are initially displayed (3 in a row, two rows), with the sixth entry containing the "More" entry to access the overflow menu.

My problem is that I can't see any difference in the code which could explain this difference in behaviour.

Does anyone know how I can have the menu of my first application to look the "new" way (the Android 4 one)?

Comment: When you say "target SDK", do you mean your build target or your `android:targetSdkVersion`?

Answer (score 0):

Application reconstructed from scratch, with a lot of cut & paste. Brute force replaced intelligence...

In fact, I only had to change the theme of my application in my AndroidManifest.xml file!